# Split string only at double hyphens and leave single hyphens

Tags: java, string, substring

I have two strings that I need to split:

1. "ninety-year-old"
2. "Macbeth--well"

They are inside a text that I'm splitting into individual words, however, 1. should just stay as it is, and 2. should end up being "Macbeth" and "well". I've been trying to use

.slip([-\s+])

but that isn't working because it also splits 1.

Comment: You failed to mention what, in particular, makes 2 splittable but not 1. Is it '2 or more dashes', or is it 'because I want it to, and I expect the computer to read my mind', or something else? As you may expect, that second thing? You can't program that.

Comment: I must be missing something.  Is there a reason not to use `s.split("--")`?

Comment: What is `slip` you tried to use?

Answer (score 0):

use `string.split("--");` i.e.

```java
String string1 = "ninety-year-old";
String string2 = "Macbeth--well";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string1.split("--")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string2.split("--")));
```

Output:

```
[ninety-year-old]
[Macbeth, well]
```